# How to set a lossless quality wallpaper?

Tags: images, home-screen, wallpaper

I'm trying to set a .png file I had prepared myself as the wallpaper, but the thing apparently (as in EVIDENTLY) gets converted to a .jpg.

It strikes me odd google.com has nothing on this issue, that's why I've come here.

**Is there a way to set a .png wallpaper without it being converted to .jpg?** A workaround app maybe?

[image: png screenshot zoomed x2, yuck!]

This is a png screenshot, scaled x2. Note the artifacts by the edge of the shape.

**EDIT: 6 JUNE 2015**
Conclusions from my investigation (and answers below) so far:

- Android stores the wallpaper file in a png
- This means the fault lies within the piece of code doing the cropping and saving the new file
- In my context (samsung a3 original firmware) I have yet to find a resolution which would bypass the cropping tool, allowing me to set the file as is

THERE ARE MEANS of achieving the effect though:

- Muzei app is quite easy to set up, streaming whatever source you like to your wallpaper (including unconverted image files -- or a single file)
- Surprisingly, Moonshine's wallpaper setter does its job the right way too, although it only handles the few graphics that are bundled with it (however lovely they are).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a workaround, you could try [Muzei](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.muzei): it is a live wallpaper, which you can set your own wallpaper to.

Comment: Indeed, Muzei uses the original file and the quality doesn't change

Comment: Okay, if that solved it for you, tick the answer as correct so that we know.

Comment: Sadly, no. >:3 While it does achieve the effect, it doesn't per se point the system wallpaper location to the file I want, nor allows me to crop the image and save it to png. It certainly is some way to get the desired effect, but probably has its overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently if you set an image as wallpaper and if you have to crop it to fit as wallpaper then it gets saved as JPG as a result of image processing.

Please try this once...Find out the target devices' resolution and then create a wallpaper in the exact dimension. This way you just set a wallpaper without any image processing.

But interestingly, the [Android developer page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) says the images for wallpaper are saved as PNG.

Comment: You've made the exactly same points as I in the meantime... Been on the developers page too. Using a file of twice the screens' width doesn't work with any combination of app that offers the functionality of setting a wallpaper, with launchers I have, including the default ones. The system is 4.4.4 on unrooted samsing a3.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). Along with its many features it allows you to set wallpapers from both within the app or from selecting from a list when choosing what wallpaper app to use.

Hopefully ES File Explorer will use the file as selected.

---

#### Steps:

(Use this method if you want to select the whole image, because if you set the background from within the app it wont be able to select  the whole image.)

1. Download and install [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop)
2. Long press on your home screen until you get to select your wallpaper

   [image: Wallpaper Select]
3. Chose ES File Explorer
4. Navigate to where your image is and select it

   [image: Select it] 
   [image: Select it 2]
5. Re-size to fit the whole image

   [image: Whole screen select]

---

**Side-note:** I don't know if this will convert your image, but from the best of my knowledge it just uses the file as is. This will allow you to select the image as a full image so hopefully it won't get '[jaggies](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/J/jaggies.html)' as shown above.